# Query fails inside loop (returns EOF)

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

My query works fine outside of the loop when I have the hard-coded values in. When I put the query inside my loop and use variables to hold the correct values it returns EOF. I've printed out the query and run it directly in SQL server and it returns the correct results. Which makes me think my SQL syntax is ok, but I can't figure out why it doesn't return anything in the loop. Any Ideas?

```
Public Function getPOs()
    Dim TotalPos, Curpo, Query, ClaimNum, Color, DCloc As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Row, Style, LastRow As LongPtr
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("test")


    ' Set up database connection
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.ConnectionString = SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION
    cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 0
    cnn.Open

    'This query works fine, it returns results that I can iterate through.
    rs.Open "SELECT PO " & _
    "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
    "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = '1337' AND STYLE = '293493' and COLOR = '03' AND DC_LOCATION = 'PFC'", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


        ' Itereate through the results
        i = 0
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            If rs![PO] = "" Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            If i = 0 Then
                Curpo = rs![PO]
                TotalPos = Curpo
            Else
                Curpo = rs![PO]
                TotalPos = TotalPos & ", " & Curpo
            End If

            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    MsgBox TotalPos ' Works fine!




    ' For some reason adding the query inside this loop messes it up.
    Row = 11
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    rs.Close
    While Row < 12 ' will change back to LastRow once working

        'Parse the claim number
        ClaimNum = Replace(ws.Cells(Row, 10), "IC - ", "")
        MsgBox ClaimNum

        'Style
        Style = Left(ws.Cells(Row, 11), Len(ws.Cells(Row, 11)) - 2)
        MsgBox Style

        'Color
        Color = ws.Cells(Row, 12)
        MsgBox Color

        'DCloc
        DCloc = ws.Cells(Row, 13)
        MsgBox DCloc

        ' When I add the query here it returns nothing...
        rs.Open "SELECT PO " & _
        "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
        "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = " & ClaimNum & " AND STYLE = " & Style & " and COLOR = '" & Color & "' AND DC_LOCATION = ' " & DCloc & "'", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

        'add the entire sql statement to the Query var so I can print it out and run it in SQL Server
        Query = "SELECT PO " & _
        "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
        "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = " & ClaimNum & " AND STYLE = " & Style & " and COLOR = '" & Color & "' AND DC_LOCATION = '" & DCloc & "'"

        ' print the query... when I run this exact thing in SQL server it returns results just fine'
        MsgBox Query

        ' iterate through results
        i = 0

        'rs.EOF now that it's in the loop... but why? I know the syntax of the query is correct, it returns results when I run it directly in SQL server
        If rs.EOF Then
            MsgBox "why???"
        End If

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            If rs![PO] = "" Then

                Exit Do
            End If
            If i = 0 Then
                Curpo = rs![PO]
                TotalPos = Curpo
            Else
                Curpo = rs![PO]
                TotalPos = TotalPos & ", " & Curpo
            End If
            MsgBox TotalPos
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    rs.Close
    Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    cnn.Close

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> rs.Open "SELECT PO " & _
> "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
> "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = " & ClaimNum & " AND STYLE = " & Style & " and COLOR = '" & Color & "' AND DC_LOCATION = ' " & DCloc & "'"
> ```

Don't concatenate parameter values into your SQL string - that way you don't need to care about quoting strings and worry about whether a string contains apostrophes, or worse - the widely-known tale of [*Little Bobby Tables*](https://xkcd.com/327/) captures just how impactful this careless value concatenation practice can be, if you let it.

Instead, define your query **once**, and let the server deal with the parameters (it's its job).

```
Const sql As String = _
    "SELECT PO " & _
    "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
    "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = ? AND STYLE = ? AND COLOR = ? AND DC_LOCATION = ?"
```

Each `?` is understood by ADODB as a positional parameter: all you need to do now, is to execute a `ADODB.Command` with 4 parameters, appended in the order they are specified.

Now you can write a `Function` that takes the values for the 4 parameters you need, and the function can return a `ADODB.Recordset` that contains the results - no need to redefine the SQL string every time you need it!

```
Private Function GetPO(ByVal cnn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal ClaimNum As String, ByVal Style As String, ByVal Color As String, ByVal DCloc As String) As ADODB.Recordset

    Const sql As String = _
        "SELECT PO " & _
        "FROM [catalog].[dbo].[table] " & _
        "WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = ? AND STYLE = ? AND COLOR = ? AND DC_LOCATION = ?"

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    'TODO: verify parameter types & sizes - here NVARCHAR(200).
    'NOTE: parameters must be added in the order they are specified in the SQL.
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=ClaimNum)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=Style)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=Color)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=DCloc)

    Set GetPO = cmd.Execute

End Function
```

You can use it from anywhere you have an `ADODB.Connection` that's ready to use:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = GetPO(cnn, ClaimNum, Style, Color, DCloc)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    '...
Loop
```

Comment: Implementing this now! I'm still fairly new to VBA and still learning best practices, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap variables in quotes to make it work, a string type isn't enough.

```
"WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = " & ClaimNum & " ...
```

Needs to become:

```
"WHERE CLAIM_NUMBER = " & "'" &  ClaimNum & "'" & " ...
```

In addition to all the other variables you are concatenating into the SQL statement

As an aside

```
Dim TotalPos, Curpo, Query, ClaimNum, Color, DCloc As String
```

is only declaring `DCloc` as a string and all the others are variants.

To make them all string you need to add `as string` to all of them.

```
Dim TotalPos as string, Curpo as string, Query as string, ClaimNum as string, Color as string, DCloc As String
```

Comment: Good call on the variable declarations. So it turns out the issue was that I had a space between my open single quote and the DCloc variable. Thank you so much your answer helped me spot it!